# Cannot publish grails plugin

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

I am trying to publish a new version of the Spring Security OAuth2 Provider grails plugin (2.0-RC1), and it seems to upload the artifacts correctly (see [here](http://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins/org/grails/plugins/spring-security-oauth2-provider/2.0-RC1/)), but the [plugin page](http://grails.org/plugin/spring-security-oauth2-provider) on grails.org is not updated.  Here is the output from publishing - I'm not sure what do about the error honestly:

```
~>grailsw publish-plugin --grailsCentral --stacktrace
| Plugin packaged grails-spring-security-oauth2-provider-2.0-RC2.zip
| Plugin packaged grails-spring-security-oauth2-provider-2.0-RC2.zip
| POM generated: target/pom.xml
Publishing to Grails Central
Publishing to http://grails.org/api/v1.0/publish/spring-security-oauth2-provider/2.0-RC2
| Error Failed to publish plugin: Could not read JSON: Can not deserialize instance of java.lang.String out of START_OBJECT token
 at [Source: sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream@74f0437f; line: 1, column: 1]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.lang.String out of START_OBJECT token
 at [Source: sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream@74f0437f; line: 1, column: 1]
```

I'm using the release plugin version 3.0.1 and grails 2.3.8.  I'm also on Windows 7 x64 with Java 7 x64.

Comment: Is this the full stacktrace? Could you intercept that variable and look what inside? Also, maybe at grails.org protocols are changed and now all problems with the release plugin.

Comment: That is the full stacktrace (I've used --stacktrace, --full-stacktrace, and --verbose and they all give the same message).  I'm not sure where the variable actually even is to even start looking at this, it doesn't give me much to work on.  I guess I can dig through the PublishPlugin.groovy script, but I wanted to see if anyone had any ideas before I really dive into that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution after finally taking the time to dig into the publish plugin code.  The problem was actually that I had a newer version of the rest-client-builder overriding the version bundled with the release plugin.  I was using version 2.0.1 instead of 1.0.3.

Changing the rest-client-builder plugin version to 1.0.3 fixed the issue (using release plugin 3.0.1).